# ngSweetAlert vertical scroll bar disappear when clicking on cancel button

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack, sweetalert

I'm using [ngSweetAlert](http://oitozero.github.io/ngSweetAlert/#/home) in my project.

It works perfectly except when I added the `showCancelButton: true` property.

Indeed, for example :

```
SweetAlert.swal({
   title: "Are you sure?",
   text: "Your will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
   type: "warning",
   showCancelButton: true,
   confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
   confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
   closeOnConfirm: false}, 
function(){ 
   //do something if "Yes, delete it!" button is clicked
});
```

When it's called, the sweet alert window appear and at this moment, the vertical scrollbar is disabled, no problem until now.

The user has two choice in this case :

- Click on button **"Yes, delete it!"** : the sweet alert disappear and my vertical scroll bar returned back.
- Click on button **"Cancel"** :
  so the sweet alert disappear but **my problem** is the fact that my vertical scroll bar is still disable, which should not be the case !

---

**One possible solution** is to add `overflow-y: auto;` css property on my `<body>` html tag but the problem is that the vertical scroll bar is not disable while sweet alert is displayed. (Which is not ideally what I want...)

Does someone has already this issue before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, you just need to add :

```
closeOnCancel: true
```

so now, it looks like this :

```
SweetAlert.swal({
   title: "Are you sure?",
   text: "Your will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
   type: "warning",
   showCancelButton: true,
   confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
   confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
   closeOnConfirm: false,
   closeOnCancel: true}, 
function(){ 
   //do something if "Yes, delete it!" button is clicked
});
```